# Find New Zealand TLA (Territorial Local Authority) from a coordinate/address in R

Tags: r, gis, geocoding

Hi there I have a bunch of ambiguous addresses that I want to work out the TLA for.
For example, my address might look like "32 Daniels Road, Wellington"

```
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "MYAPIKEY") 

geocode("21 Daniels Street, Wellington", output = "more")

**OUTPUT**

lon   lat type    loctype address                                                  north south  east  west
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                                                    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  175. -41.3 premise rooftop 21 daniell street, newtown, wellington 6021, new zealand -41.3 -41.3  175.  175.
```

In an ideal world, I would be able to get the following information:

- **IDEAL OUTPUT**
- original_address = 21 Daniels Street, Wellington
- found_address = daniell street, newtown, wellington 6021
- street_name = Daniell Street
- suburb = Newtown
- city_or_town = Wellington
- tla = Wellington City

I think I need a list of TLA (Territorial Local Authorities) that either have boundary coordinates, or alternatively a lookup table of cities/towns and their associated TLA's - in which case I could pull out the town or city and then match it to a TLA. But I havent been able to find such a list, either through StatsNZ or Linz

Comment: Second entry in this list is territorial authorities. 
 https://datafinder.stats.govt.nz/data/category/annual-boundaries/2022/  You can download the shapefile (or KML seems to work better), but I have no idea how you'd use it in R

Comment: Thanks - I saw that. My issue is that I dont know how to match between coordinates (which is what I have) and shapefiles etc. Maybe someone who knows GIS can point me there. :)

Comment: If you know a priori that your addresses are all in New Zealand, you could constrain the geocoder to only consider NZ addresses and would get good matches. (As opposed to [all the other Wellingtons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellington_(disambiguation)#Places).) Your geocoder's definition of a city may not strictly correspond to the formal TLA, if that matters. Once you have a geocoded location, joining it to the current TLA set is a different question.

Comment: Yeah all my addresses are within NZ. Any ideas for joining it to a list of TLAs?